# Ver imagen almacenada en carpeta privada de laravel

Tags: laravel, blade

necesito guardar en un carpeta privada la foto de perfil de cada usuario, las estoy almacenando en storage/uploads y en la bd guardo una ruta como esta storage/uploads/prueba.jpg.

El problema esta que no puedo recuperar la imagen, estoy usando el helper asset, me retorna la ruta correcta pero la imagen no se ve.

```
 <img src="{{ asset(auth()->user()->foto) }}" alt="Foto de perfil"
                class="rounded-circle mx-auto d-block">
```

El asset me devuelve algo como esto

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/prueba.jpg" alt="Foto de perfil" class="rounded-circle mx-auto d-block">
```

Tengo algunas imágenes públicas, pero ahora necesito almacenar imágenes privadas, en este caso, la foto de perfil de cada usuario, las públicas las guarde en storage/app/public e hice el storage link y funciona perfecto.

Y las privadas las guarde en storage/app/uploads pero no sé cómo acceder, cualquier ayuda me sirve.

Me comentan que no se puede usar el helper asset para archivos privados, entonces cree una ruta y su función para recuperar, pero me sigue marcando error 404.

```
Route::get('storage/{file}', function ($file) {
    $path = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
    return response()->file($path);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

dado que estaba utilizando el helper asset y necesitaba recuperar imagenes en una carpeta privada, tuve que utilizar una ruta con la siguiente funcion.

```
Route::get('storage/{file}', function ($file) {
    $path = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
    return response()->file($path);
})->name('uploads');
```

En la base de datos estoy guardando solo el nombre del archivo y su formato, en la vista recupero la imagen de la siguiente forma.

```
<img src="{{ route('uploads', ['file' => auth()->user()->foto]) }}" alt="Foto de perfil"
                class="rounded-circle mx-auto d-block">
```